# I'm looking to have my menu underlined when active, instead of just hover. Is that possible? (not regular underline code)

Tags: html, css

so I'm using some CSS code I found on CodePen to have a nice underline on my menu for my website, so it's not using the regular underline that's applied to links.

Currently, it's set to underline when hovering with a slight animation effect but I'd like it to underline when active instead of hover. I've tried using multiple ways around it but as it's not completely my code for the underline, some parts confuse me.

Could someone help? I apologise if it looks a mess and I can grab other bits of code if needed. Thanks a lot.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS (code from codepen):

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none!important;
}

nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    padding: 15px;
}

a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 0;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) all;
    transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) all;
}

a:hover {
    color: tomato;
}

a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You can add a class to the active navigation item, then style the class to be the same as the hover. This should accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: Just change `a:hover:after` to this `a.active:after`

Comment: `:active` has a very short lifespan: This special underline starts when `mousedown` and it ends on `mouseup`, or beginning of a click and ends when the click is released. If you have the underline on `:hover` you won't even notice `:active`.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a class that has the same styles as the hover style.

Turn this:

```
a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Into this:

```
a.active:after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then just add the class to the `a`:

```
<li class="item"><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
```

```css
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style:none;
}

ul li {
    float: left;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

nav li a {
   
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    padding: 15px;
}

a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 0;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) all;
    transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) all;
}

a:hover {
    color: tomato;
}

/*a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}*/

a.active:after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="item"><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, got it sorted now. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, do not really understand , is 15px padding in the 'a'.
You could add that better stuff to the 'li'. Another developer who recommends using [Firefox Developer](https://www.mozilla.org/es-ES/firefox/developer/), your style editor is a great help, pointing out possible objects to see your property in this way.

[image]

in this way you can interpret by the color of the rules that your element takes your apatir size from its padding.

```css
a:link {
text-decoration: none!important;
}

nav li a {
color: #fff;
font-size: 14px;
position: relative;
letter-spacing: 2px;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
transition: all 0.4s ease;
margin: 15px;

}


a:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
height: 2px;
background-color: white;
width: 0;
left: 50%;
bottom: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%);
-webkit-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) all;
transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) all;
}

a:hover {
color: tomato;
}

a:active:after {
width: 100%;
}
body{background-color:black}
```

```html
<nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Comment: _"... but I'd like it to underline when active instead of hover"_ How does this solve that problem?